# Reduction of endomorphism ring of Non-CM elliptic curve

Tags: elliptic-curves, ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $E$ be an elliptic curve defined over a number field without complex multiplication and with ordinary reduction at a prime $p\in\mathbb{N}$. When is the reduction mod $p$ map a surjection on the endomorphism ring I.e. $\overline{End(E)} \cong End(\overline{E})$?

Comment: Never.  An elliptic curve over a finite field always has an extra endomorphism, namely Frobenius.

Comment: Perhaps it is worth noting that Frobenius can be a rational integer (necessarily $\pm q^{n/2}$) but of course this forces the curve to be supersingular.

Comment: A reference for gb's comment: Lang's "Elliptic Functions", Chapter 13, Section 2, Theorem 5.